# How to assign vat value calling from php to Javascript for my function in easy way?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I want to assign a value ($productVatValue) taking from php to javascript using JSON, how I can achieve that for my code?

here is the code on Javascript

```
var vat = (Number($("#subTotal").val())/100) * $productVatValue;
    vat = vat.toFixed(2);
    $("#vat").val(vat);
    $("#vatValue").val(vat);
```

and here is the fetchOrderVat.php that calls the vat value

```
<?php   

require_once 'core.php';

 
$sql = "SELECT vat FROM usercompany WHERE id = 1";
$result = $connect->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0) { 
 $row = $result->fetch_array();
} // if num_rows

$connect->close();

echo json_encode($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a little change in your first line of javascript code.

Simply change

`var vat = (Number($("#subTotal").val())/100) * $productVatValue;`

to

`var vat = (Number($("#subTotal").val())/100) * <?php echo $productVatValue; ?>`

Comment: thanks for the help. The change creates an error "parsing error: unexpected token <"
also, how $productVatValue; will be passed from the fetchOrderVat.php as there is no link established? can you help me with that please?

Comment: can you please edit the question and share the json `fetchOrderVat.php`